# How to render custom html in bootstrapTable but when using sidePagination and url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I am using https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table on some project.
I find that is really easy to use and implement pagination. However I have some problem regarding custom html in different rows. This is just peace of code.

```
$('#selector').bootstrapTable({

    pagination: true,
    url : some_rest_url,
    sidePagination: 'server',
    onLoadSuccess: function (res) {
        var data_ = [];
        var rows = res.rows;

        for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i ++) {
            var data = {};
            var item = rows[i];
            $.each(item, function (key, value) {
                if (key == "cost") value = "< span class="cl" >"currency + " " + parseFloat(value).formatNumber(2, '.', ',')."< / span >";
               //and so on some more styling and formatting for other elements/columns of table
               data[key] = value;
           });
           data_.push(data);
    }
    $('#selector').bootstrapTable("load", data_);
```

So table should have one column and in each row span element with that class but that is not happening.
I just have that default plain text data from boostrapTable default load (json data).

BTW when using plain ajax call instead of that default boostrapTable pagination thingy everything works great but then i have to make custom pagination (and using sidePagination = client is just wrong and working slow when have like 1000 records ).

Comment: for some example i can see i can use formatter: operateFormatter, but fck. closing question.

Answer (score 2):

After wasting couple of hours, solution was to use formatter for columns. For example:

```
field: 'column_name',
formatter: operateFormatter

function operateFormatter(value, row, index){
//value is text from json
//row is all values from json for that row
}
```

well this way, code will be much more clearer.